# Possible to retrieve non-primary email addressees for a user from Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook allows users to have multiple email addresses associated with their account, with one of those emails being the "primary" email address.

The /me call on the Facebook Graph API returns the primary email address by default:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me

Or you can access just the email address using /me?fields=email:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Demail

Is it possible to retrieve the user's non-primary email addresses from the graph API? I'm interested in using this to help match up a Facebook user with any existing accounts they might have on a service.

Comment: It looks like this is a duplicate of the question asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617085/how-to-retrieve-all-email-addresses-in-facebook-through-api - that answer from 2011 says that it's not possible, how about now in 2014?

Comment: Nope, the previous answer is still correct